# How to echo out elements from two different but related MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I have these two tables in MySQL. One is called 'History' and one is called 'Annotated'.

The 'History' table is full of random YouTube video id's that can be repeated. The 'Annotated' table contains a unique copy of each video id along with a description of that id. Looks something like this:

```
History                            Annotated

video id                   video id         description

id_1                       id_1             description_1
id_1                       id_2             description_2
id_3                       id_3             description_3
id_2                       id_4             description_4
id_3                       etc.             etc.
id_1
id_4
id_2
etc.
```

Okay so the History table's order is VERY important. I want to print the order (duplicates and all) onto my page but I want to print their respective descriptions from the Annotated table beside them so it looks like this:

```
id_1   -    description_1
id_1   -    description_1
id_3   -    description_3
id_2   -    description_2
id_3   -    description_3  
id_1   -    description_1
id_4   -    description_4
id_2   -    description_2
etc.        etc.
```

So far I've queried the database and made an array of all the videoid's from history I want to print. The code looks like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `videoid` FROM `History` WHERE BLAH BLAH;");
$idVideoColumn = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $idVideoColumn[] = $row['videoid'];
}
$implodedIdVideo = "'".implode("', '", $idVideoColumn)."'";
```

So I've got my list of videoid's ready for a MySQL query contained in the variable $implodedIdVideo. Anyone know if it's possible to print what I'm trying to do? (And please no answers about my deprecated MySQL syntax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, I can't get it to work with the join table. My knowledge of MySQL just isn't good enough. I've decided to do it the bulky inflexible way.

```
$query4 = mysql_query("SELECT `videoid` FROM `History` WHERE BLAH BLAH;");
$idVideoColumn = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query4)){
    $idVideoColumn[] = $row['videoid'];
}
$implodedIdVideo = "'".implode("', '", $idVideoColumn)."'";
$length = count($idVideoColumn);



$i = 0;
while($i < $length) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `description` FROM `Annotated` WHERE `videoid` = '".$idVideoColumn[$i]."';");
    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $idVideoColumn[$i] . " --- " . $result['description']."<br /><br />";
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT h.videoid, a.description
    FROM history h
        INNER JOIN annotated a
            ON h.videoid = a.videoid
    WHERE blah blah
    ORDER BY h.SomeColumnForOrdering;
```

Comment: Could you explain what's happening here a bit? I'm having trouble getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
   $sql =  select video_id , description from history A , annotated B   where A.video_id = B.video_id ORDER BY A.video_id DESC;
```

you have to preform join in order to get desire result .

you paste the wrong code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
      $idVideoColumn[] = $row['videoid'];
}
```

$idvideoCoulm should be empty because you are using mysql_fetch_array to fetch the result then you assign $row['videoid'] to $idVideoColumn[] with name index. this is could never happen bacause mysql_fetch_array always return the value by array index you should use mysql_fetch_assoc.

```
$str = "" ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
      $str .= $row['videoid'] . ',' . $row['description'] ; 
}
```